# Swift Combine makeConnectable with PassthroughSubject

Tags: swift, combine

I'm having a hard time using the `Connectable` protocol on a `PassthroughSubject`. What I would like to do is be able to control when the `PassthroughSubject` begins sending events to its subscribers.

```
let eventPublisher = PassthroughSubject<String, Never>().makeConnectable()
let subscriber = MySubscriber()
eventPublisher.subscribe(subscriber)

eventPublisher.send("Hello") // Does not compile, send not found in Publisher.MakeConnectable

let cancelable = eventPublisher.connect()
// expect MySubscriber to recieve "Hello"
```

I'm new to Combine, but I don't understand how I can send values downstream to subscribers after becoming a connectable publisher and calling `connect()`. The docs are quite sparse on this topic and I'm hoping someone can show me how to achive this behavior.

Comment: Example here: http://www.apeth.com/UnderstandingCombine/operators/operatorswrappers.html

Answer (score 2):

You're close, but misunderstanding what the [makeConnectable](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/publishers/makeconnectable) enables. It doesn't "queue up" data and prepare it for sending when it's available, it controls when the subscription is established.

As soon as the subscription is allowed (with `.connect()`), the publisher "is live" and a subscriber would receive a value that you send. However, anything you send before `connect()` is invoked is essentially dropped, not queued.

That said, if you invoke `eventPublisher.send('after connect')` after the last line, that will be received by the subscriber.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you want is a CurrentValueSubject, not a PassthroughSubject.

```
let countPublisher = CurrentValueSubject<Int,Never>(0)

var storage = Set<AnyCancellable>()

func f() {
    self.countPublisher.value = 1
    self.countPublisher
        .sink {print($0)} // 1
        .store(in:&self.storage)
}
```

As you can see, we can prime the pump with a stored value before any subscriber comes along, and when a subscriber does come along, it immediately receives the stored value. And after that, we can say `.send` and the subscriber(s) will receive whatever we send.

Comment: worth noting - a side effect of CurrentValueSubject: you always have to start with a value, and as soon as anything is allowed to subscribe, it *always* gets the current value as soon as the subscription process goes through. You can also think of it as a "remember only a single value" queue that you have to pre-fill with a default value that will be served up if no other values have been provided through `.send()`

Comment: Yes, I agree of course. I was just trying to guess what the OP might be after, from the description where `connect` is immediately followed by a Hello that was sent _earlier_.

Comment: It may not have been what the OP was after, but your solution certainly was what *I* needed!  so thanks  and I found it from the OP's question, so you're doing some think right here.